# Sqlite3 join tables with result

Tags: sqlite

I have created 2 tables, 
1 reservations (timestamp,name,phone,date,time,tableNo)
2 tables (tableId, TableNo)

Users are able to add and select entries from lists in a form 
but when they reach table list i want to run a query which will check saved reservations (table1 time & tableNO) and their time is greater than a given variable, so the table2 will have to show next to table number the name and time of a saved reservation,
Hope this makes some sense:

```
reservations                                      tables
name   date   time    tableNO                        1
John   20/5   12:30    5                             2 
Mary   20/5   15:00    2                             3
                                                     4
                                                     5
```

What i want to achieve is:

SELECT FROM tables .... WHERE time > 13:00

```
   reservations                                      tables
    name   date   time    tableNO                        1
    John   20/5   12:30    5                             2 Mary
    Mary   20/5   15:00    2                             3
                                                         4
                                                         5
```

Comment: Please update your question to make it more clear what you're asking and to show anything you've tried so far.

Comment: Updated. where the dots, should be some inner join, but i don't know how.

Comment: The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) is quite extensive and helpful for formatting queries.

Comment: Don't tell us what is shown on the screen. What is the desired actual output of the query?

Comment: What I've written is just a demo, and the second table is the desired output.

Comment: So you want a query that outputs the value `2`?